# how to solve a Not a Directory error message in UNIX

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, sh

I have created a directory with the following command

```
/usr/bin/mkdir -p  "${exa}/isrvce-backup";
```

exa ---> /sample/example

and I see isrvce-backup is created, when I tried to access that folder, I get the following error message

```
isrvce-backup is not a Directory
```

Can any one help how to resolve this issue and I am using Shell script

When I execute `ls` command I can see `isrvce-backup` entry in that list

I tried to access that folder, as `cd isrvce-backup` command

**Edit :** After Executing the `ls -l isrvc*` command I get the following output

```
-rwx------+ username none 37 date/time  isrvce-backup
```

if I see the desc of the isrvce-backup folder, it seems to be file.

**I am wondering how mkdir will create a folder with file persmissions, instead as a complete Directory**

2) I tried creating the same directory directly in the unix box, it worked fine
but some how its not wokring from the shell script.

Comment: Please show how you try to access that directory.

Comment: cd isrvce-backup with the above command and from the appropriate path

Comment: what do you see when you run `ls -l`? also, try running `cd $PWD`, and then try again.

Comment: try running `file isrvce-backup`, `cat isrvce-backup`, try deleting `isrvce-backup` and recreating it using the same command.

Comment: /usr/bin/mkdir -p  "${exa}/isrvce-backup"; i am executing from Shell script, suppose if I create that command from console, all seems to be fine

Comment: Maybe your shell script has not permission for `mkdir`; you should test that `mkdir` was successful. And for debugging that shell script start it with `#!/bin/sh -vx` as its first line (and make the script executable with `chmod a+x`)

Comment: `-rwx------+..` this means, it is a file, not a directory. directory should start with `d` so your `mkdir` just does what `touch` does??

Comment: @kent, Please let me know how can I correct this

Comment: `ls -l isrvc*` will show you the *contents* of a directory named isrvce-backup (if it exists as a directory) or the properties of the file isrvce-backup (if it exists as a file), but not tell you which it is doing. Please use `ls -ld isrvc*` instead (the `-d` makes it show a directory's info, not its contents). If that still shows it as a file, then I'm pretty sure it's not the mkdir command that's the problem -- something *else* is creating it as a file, and you'll need to track that something down.

Comment: This question is quite old, but I can usually solve the problem by touching the directory (`touch <dir>`). Not sure about the reasons, but it may force the inode to be sync'ed or so.

Answer (score 3):

I coudln't reproduce the error you mentioned. I use bash-3.2 and see the directory being created as intended.. If you are trying this with bash, then please specify your bash version (or any other shell), exact code snippet causing this error and the output of following commands on the directory being created (cat,ls -l,file,stat) etc..

```
$ cat mkdir.sh
#! /bin/bash
exa="/sample"
mkdir -p "${exa}/c"
touch "${exa}/c/d"
file "${exa}/c/d"

$ sudo bash mkdir.sh  ## asks password as the dir is being created on /
Password: 
/sample/c/d: empty

$ ls -l /sample/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  3 root  wheel  102 Mar  9 18:02 c

$ ls -l /sample/c
total 0
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  0 Mar  9 18:07 d
```

Comment: welcome to SO, as this is answering the question please consider using the comment section

Comment: @AbuRomaïssae hey you meant 'not answering' right? yeah, i wanted to put it in comments only but i am not seeing the 'add comment' under the question., and also my comment contains actual code to do what questioner wanted (so doesn't fit in comments section and also might be an actual 'answer' as well).. :)

Comment: if you are not seeing the put comment link, that is you don't have privileges to do so yet, and you will need to gain some reputation, also when you have some code snipet in your comment, you can use some services as: [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/)